# Complex exponential arrangement

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers, exponential-function

> Let
>
> $$z = e^{-\frac{a}{b + ic}}$$
>
> (where $i$ is the imaginary unit and $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$) be a
>   complex number in exponential form.
>
> Write $z$ in the following form:
>
> $$z = e^{- A}e^{-B}$$
>
> with $A \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{ 0 \}$, $B \in \mathbb{C}$.

I tried

$$\frac{a}{b + ic} \frac{b - ic}{b - ic} = \frac{a}{b^2 + c^2} (b - ic)$$

So

$$A = \frac{ab}{b^2 + c^2}, \ B = -\frac{iac}{b^2 + c^2}$$

Is this the only way to split the above exponent $a / (b + ic)$, or are there other ways to get a real $A$ and a purely imaginary (or complex) $B$?

Comment: You could split $\frac{a}{b^2 + c^2} (b - ic)$ into $\frac{ab}{b^2 + c^2}  - \frac{ic}{b^2 + c^2}$, but apart from that there is not much you can do.

Comment: @TimTheEnchanter Yes, of course, I didn't write it but it was tacit. So, you think there is no other way to split the original $a / (b + ic)$?

Comment: Well one could fiddle with the periodicity of the complex exponential in $e^B$ ( add or subtract $\mathrm n \pi$) , but that isn't very meaningful. The value of the expression for z still remains unique.

Comment: A pretty strange (or incomplete ?) question. $A=0,B=a/(b+ic)$ solves it.

Comment: @YvesDaoust You are right; I forgot to write that the trivial solution $A = 0$ should not be accepted.

Comment: @BowPark: not so helpful. Another solution can be $A=x,B=a/(b+ic)-x$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Again, right. $\exp (-a / (b + ic))$ is a complex number with an amplitude (to which $e^{-A}$ would contribute) and a phase. Maybe a **part** of the complex exponent $-a / (b + ic)$ may contribute to the amplitude. The question is looking for this part.

Comment: @BowPark: as long as you allow $B$ complex, there is no unique solution. This was said in the accepted answer.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I didn't immediately observe this when making the question and it is a correct remark. The answer below pointed it out too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Purely imaginary $B$**

The real $A$ is unique. This is because when $z=\rho e^{i\theta}\in\mathbb{C}\backslash\{0\}$ where $\rho\in\mathbb{R}^+$ and $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$, $\rho$ is unique as $\rho=|z|$. To have the desired form, the only possibility for $A$ is such that $e^{-A}=\rho$, and that is $A=-\ln{\rho}=\ln{\frac{1}{\rho}}$.

$B$, on the other hand, is not unique. Recall that $$\forall\theta\in\mathbb{R},\,e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$$ and since $\cos$ and $\sin$ are $2\pi$-periodic, we have $$\forall\theta\in\mathbb{R},\forall n\in\mathbb{Z},e^{i\theta}=e^{i(\theta+2\pi n)}$$

Thus, if $B$ is such that $z=e^{-A}e^{-B}$ then for any $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, $B_n=B+2\pi n$ satisfies $z=e^{-A}e^{-B_n}$ and $B_n$ is purely imaginary.

**Complex $B$**

When you don't ask for $B$ to be purely imaginary, even $A$ isn't unique:$$z=e^{-A}e^{-B}=e^{-\frac{A}{2}}e^{-\left(\frac{A}{2}+B\right)}=e^{-(A+B)}$$